# Can't figure out how to get DirectX 12 UWP in Visual Studio 2017 Community

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017

I made a game a couple years back on Windows 7 in DirectX 10 and can't get it to run on my Windows 10 machine. I tried this sometime last year but the changes to DirectX 12 in Win10 was so overwhelming that I gave up, but now I'd like to try again. Could someone advise me on how to get the DirectX 12 app (Universal Windows) installed on Visual Studio 2017? The installer is quite different from VS2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to get the DirectX 12 app (Universal Windows) installed on Visual Studio 2017

Open your Visual Studio 2017, create a new project with `DirectX12 App(Universal Windows)` template. The template is under Templates->Visual C++->Windows Universal.
[image]

If you cannot find the template, you can launch the installer again from the New project dialog and add the missed components. Details please reference [Download or update Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/get-set-up). `Universal Windows Platform development`   component is required. And also make sure the optional component  `C++ Universal Windows Platform tools` are installed as following picture shows.

[image]

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/tutorial--create-your-first-metro-style-directx-game) is a tutorial for creating a simple UWP game with DirectX you may reference to begin your developing on DirectX 12 UWP.

Answer (score 0):

You can install some templates that will easily allow for DX12 projects [from here](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/releases).